# process wildcards in bash scripts

Tags: bash

I just need a simple example of a bash script to proccess a single file or multiple files if wildcard is passed as arguments

if I run

```
myscript file1
```

do something with file, and if I issue

```
myscript *.pdf
```

do something with file matching criteria

Can anybody give a simple example?

Answer (score 10):

The `*.pdf` will be expanded by the shell before executing the script, so the script won't see `*.pdf`, it will see the matching filenames directly:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#! /bin/sh

printf "|%s|\n" "$@"
$ touch {1..10}.pdf
$ ./foo.sh 1.pdf
|1.pdf|
$ ./foo.sh *.pdf
|1.pdf|
|10.pdf|
|2.pdf|
|3.pdf|
|4.pdf|
|5.pdf|
|6.pdf|
|7.pdf|
|8.pdf|
|9.pdf|
```

Within a bash script, you can use `"$@"` to get all the arguments passed to it, or use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to access the first, second, etc. argument directly.

You can just loop over all arguments with a plain `for`:

```
for i     # Or, for i in "$@"
do
    echo "Processing argument $i"
done
```

Will output:

```
Processing argument 1.pdf
Processing argument 10.pdf
Processing argument 2.pdf
Processing argument 3.pdf
Processing argument 4.pdf
Processing argument 5.pdf
Processing argument 6.pdf
Processing argument 7.pdf
Processing argument 8.pdf
Processing argument 9.pdf
```

Comment: to be thourough: it won't see the pattern IF there is at least 1 file matching that pattern? But if there are no *.pdf files in the current directory of the person typing `script *.pdf`, the script will indeed receive `*.pdf` as the shell couldn't replace it with any filenames.  And one can pass `*.pdf` by putting it inside quotes ( `"*.pdf"` or `'*.pdf'` ) or escaping the * ( `\*.pdf` )

Answer (score 3):

Here is one reading in your file(s) as an array allowing you to work with it as you please:

```
#!/bin/bash

filearray=( "$@" )

if [ ${#filearray[@]} -gt "1" ] || [ ${#filearray[@]} == "0" ]; then
    isare=are
    ent=entries
else
    isare=is
    ent=entry
fi

echo "There $isare ${#filearray[@]} $ent."
echo ""
if [ ${#filearray[@]} == "0" ]; then
    echo "Nothing entered."
    exit
else
    echo "This is what you entered or what was found: "
    echo ""
    printf '%s\n' "${filearray[@]}"
fi
```

Using the "" for the array makes it so that it will read files even if they have spaces and won't separate them when they print.  I also added wording changes based on the number of files found.  No entry will show 0.  The `${#filearray[@]}` counts the number of elements, where `${filearray[@]}` will show all elements.

Examples:

*One entry:*

```
$ ./myscript myfile.txt
There is 1 entry.

This is what you entered or what was found: 

myfile.txt
```

*Multiple entries:*

```
$ ./myscript *.sh
There are 5 entries.

This is what you entered or what was found: 

blue-ray_encode.sh
lightsOn.sh
removeoffender.sh
test1.sh
test.sh
```

*No entries:*

```
$ ./myscript 
There are 0 entries.

Nothing entered.
```